# How to remove multi indexing from a pandas pivot table for easy visualisation

Tags: python, pandas, histogram, plotly

When creating pivot tables there is often multi level indexing (two or more levels of index which show up as columns.

In these cases the object that the pivot function returns is still a dataframe but to my limited knowledge it is difficult to chart in this multi index form.

How do you go from a pivot table where you get the counts of one column line industry to putting that into a histogram with a charting library like plotly or d3 or bokeh or pygal or searborn without extracting series out of the pivot dataframe and creating a new dataframe with just one column index specifically for the visualisation.

Comment: I explained what I have done - a simple pivot chart of the number of times each value in the industry column of a dataframe has occurred. This pivot results in a multi index which I want to visualise using a visualisation library like searborn, plotly etc

Comment: `reset_index` can be used to convert all the indices in a MultiIndex to columns creating a normal dataframe with no loss of data.

Comment: Instead of reset _ index can you just say I just want the first level of index which would be "industry name", "count"?

Comment: You can use reset_index to drop or move levels you want. Having a reproducible example with desired output would help convey your question better

Comment: Thanks vamsi I'll try to add an example

Answer (score 0):

Vamsi I tried reset the index multiple times on my industry pivot table example (above) and no matter how many times I reset the index I'm still left with a dataframe which has a multi index which makes it hard for me to graph/chart.